# How to Integrate Robotium test cases and Testlink, also send the result back to testlink

Tags: integration, robotium, testlink

Testlink is a test management tool and i want to trigger robotium test cases from testlink and get the result back to testlink..**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I know of is to use the [Test Link plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TestLink+Plugin) for [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

You basically map the name of the junit test to the test in testlink and it will automatically bring across the results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have already checked Jenkins but something happened in my system so I was unable to run tests from Jenkins. It might be the wrong ADT plugin. Now I am stuck with this, can you please brief the procedure of setting up Jenkins for android Robotium testing and the Testlink integration for the same.....it would be very helpful for me, thanks again.

Comment: I would suggest https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin it pretty much sorts out all the android side on your jenkins machine and then hopefully your project has all the required dependencies to work.